# How to handle related entities

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

How to build app state if I have related entities using **ngrx-store** (redux)?

For example, I have model called "Post" and rest api returns json like this:

```
[
   { id: 1, title: 'Title 1', user: { id: 1, name: 'User name' } },
   { id: 2, title: 'Title 2', user: { id: 1, name: 'User name' } },
]
```

What the best way to store that data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single, best way to store the data, but you [should store relational data in a normalized fashion](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state). For example, you could store it something like this:

```
{
  "posts": { 
    "1": { 
      id: 1,
      title: "Title 1",
      user: 1
    },
    "2": { 
      id: 2,
      title: "Title 2",
      user: 1
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User name"
    }
  }
}
```

[normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) can be helpful in re-arranging relational data for storage in a Redux store.

Also, there is a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42472642/6680611) that contains additional references.

Comment: Thank you! If somebody find example pls feel free to tell us)